# matlab: making color brightness proportional to number of overlapping surfaces

Tags: matlab

**What I'm Trying to Do**

I am plotting ellipsoids as surfaces using MATLAB.

When two ellipsoids overlap, I would like the intensity of that ellipsoid to be twice as high as that of an isolated ellipsoid.

If the ellipsoids only overlap partially, then the increased intensity should be restricted to the volume of overlap.

**What I've Tried**

I accomplished a similar thing for 2D scatter plots with overlapping points by reducing the transparency of each point so that multiple overlapping points produce a spot that is proportional to the number of coincident points.

**My Question**

How can the same task be achieved with surfaces?

Although MATLAB does change the brightness to indicate overlap, the gain in brightness is not proportional to the number of overlapping ellipsoids. For instance, in the example below, the central ellipsoid is actually a cluster of 10, but this cannot be readily perceived based on intensity compared to the surrounding ellipsoids, which are mostly isolated or only partially overlapping.

[image]

Comment: If the increase is done via transparency, it is probably asymptotic.

Comment: Asymptotic behavior is acceptable, so long as the asymptote does not occur too early (e.g., 90% of asymptotic value for n = 10 or 20 would be fine).

Comment: You can define colormaps as a grid (think of it as a "local" axis). Given that all of these surface objects lie on a shared axis, then you can have some behind-the-scenes processing that matches each surface object's local colormap to the shared axis. Then, dynamically assign darker "redder" colors to portions of the colormaps that overlap more often on the shared axis, and "bluer" colors to portions that have no overlaps. It would take some time to implement this suggestion in an answer, so I'll leave the idea here as a comment.

Comment: I was thinking to just decrease the alpha value to something less than 50%, so that overlaps produce a more marked effect.

Comment: That's definitely simpler :) @MadPhysicist

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I adopted the same strategy for the 2D density plot I described (tuning the transparency setting based on the density of points), but this does not work well for surfaces. For the posted image, I used `'FaceAlpha',0.5, 'EdgeAlpha',0.5`; decreasing to 0.1 does not help much and going below 0.1, the surfaces become difficult to see.

Comment: @VladislavMartin: I thought of doing something along those lines (computing overlap and adjusting colors based on the overlap value), though I am hoping that there will turn out to be a simpler solution. Thanks.

Comment: There's a worked out solution for detecting where surfaces overlap (depending on how your surfaces are defined) in this [answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93623-how-do-i-plot-the-line-of-intersection-between-two-surfaces). Similarly (if your surfaces are 2D), you could use [`inpolygon`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html) to detect points (which combine to become regions) where the surfaces intersect, and color them appropriately.

Comment: @VladislavMartin: Thanks, I'll take a look.